# How to reference DOMWindow type in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I check if a variable is of type DOMWindow in Google Chrome? When I try referencing the DOMWindow type, I get a ReferenceError. For example, when I try checking the type of **window** in the console:

```
> window instanceof DOMWindow

   ReferenceError: DOMWindow is not defined
```

But **window** is clearly of type DOMWindow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. window is an object...of type DOMWindow.

Comment: I don't see the DOMWindow type in my Chrome. Are you sure that it's a type?

Comment: @Mohamed - There are no classes in Javascript, your statement is empty.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: If you type "window" in the console you get back "DOMWindow", which is an expandable tree. That's what is confusing to me. What type should I be checking against?

Comment: @ShawnOHern Although I like @Reid's answer below, can you tell us why you have a variable that you are not sure if it's a window or not? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You get a reference error `ReferenceError: DOMWindow is not defined` because there is no `DOMWindow` member on the global object to check against.

You get the same error if you type `window instanceof rubbish`

`window.constructor.name` may give you what you want (a string "DOMWindow" to check against), althogh I should warn you that it's [non-standard.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Comment: window.constuctor.name will work fine for me. It's unfortunate that it's non-standard, but this is for an extension, so it only has to work in Chrome anyway. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.constructor`. Example:

```
alert(window.constructor);
```

That should give DOMWindow or some variation thereof, at least in Chrome.